# ERROR in ./node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/uuid/uuid.web.js

Tags: sqlite, expo, uuid, cryptojs

ERROR in ./node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/uuid/uuid.web.js:9:8
Module not found: Can't resolve 'crypto'
7 |   const cryptoObject =
8 |     typeof crypto === 'undefined' || typeof crypto.randomUUID === 'undefined'

> 9 |       ? require('crypto')
> |        ^
> 10 |       : crypto;
> 11 |
> 12 |   if (!cryptoObject?.randomUUID) {

This error appears when I am trying to 'npx expo start' a simple application that can allow a user to login. The db is sqlite (if relevant).

What exactly does this mean, why is it an error, and how do i fix this?

Tried various chatgpt bits of advice but nothing working.